Craft 5 - Display Matrix fields "Open"
I find the UX of the Matrix Fields in Craft 5 a downgrade from craft 4.
Is it possible to show the matrix blocks "open", everything can be edited directly on the page without double-clicking everything?
Matrix Blocks in Craft 5 

Matrix Blocks in Craft 4 ✅


Yes, you just need to switch the view mode in the matrix's settings to "inline-editable blocks":


Awesome. Thank you  I would have never found this.
